# Embedded Tomcat 9 upgrade from 7 results in JDBC Resources being dropped from JNDI

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, tomcat7, tomcat9

I have a perfectly functional standalone product using embedded Tomcat 7.0.70 with Spring 5.3.20 which interacts with several databases and provides a REST API interface.
However when I attempt to upgrade Tomcat to 9.0.62, it seems the JDBC Context Resources declared in the Tomcat object are not being  preserved in the JNDI Context.

Please may I have some assistance to preserve these DataSources in a way that minimizes code changes?

I have already attempted the fix proposed here: [Tomcat: How to programmatically define a Datasource Resource in GlobalNamingResources and link it to apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407349/tomcat-how-to-programmatically-define-a-datasource-resource-in-globalnamingreso) without success. It also required me to instantiate DataSource objects (among other Tomcat Context listeners), which makes the code hardwired to specific database vendors. Something I wish to avoid at almost all costs. :)

I am not using any XML files, instead building the Tomcat instance (and Spring) entirely using code.
Here are my POM changes:

```
    <jre.version>11</jre.version>
    <org.springframework.version>5.3.20</org.springframework.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>5.7.1</org.springframework.security.version>
    <!-- Old Tomcat version
    <org.apache.tomcat.version>7.0.70</org.apache.tomcat.version>
    <org.apache.tomcat.logging.version>7.0.70</org.apache.tomcat.logging.version>
     -->
    <org.apache.tomcat.version>9.0.62</org.apache.tomcat.version>
    <org.apache.tomcat.logging.version>9.0.0.M6</org.apache.tomcat.logging.version>
```

Here is the code setting up Tomcat (edited to remove non-relevant code):

```
    final File base = createBaseDirectory();
    logger.info( "REST temp folder: " + base.getAbsolutePath() );
    apiServer = new Tomcat();
    apiServer.setBaseDir( base.getAbsolutePath() );
    context = apiServer.addContext( "", base.getAbsolutePath() );

    // Cross-Domain filter
    FilterDef corsFilterDef = new FilterDef();
    CORSFilter filter = new CORSFilter();
    corsFilterDef.setFilter( filter );
    corsFilterDef.setFilterName("corsFilter");
    context.addFilterDef(corsFilterDef);
    FilterMap filterMap = new FilterMap();
    filterMap.addURLPattern( "/*" );
    filterMap.addURLPattern( "/rest/*" );
    filterMap.setFilterName("corsFilter");
    context.addFilterMap(filterMap);

    context.addParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
    context.addParameter( "contextConfigLocation", SpringWebConfig.class.getName() );

    context.addContainerListener( new ApiContainerListener() );
    context.addApplicationListener( ContextLoaderListener.class.getName() );
    context.setParentClassLoader( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() );
    
    // CXF Servlet for the REST API
    Tomcat.addServlet( context, "CXFServlet", new CXFServlet() );
    //  context.addServletMapping( "/rest/*", "CXFServlet" ); *** Tomcat 7.0.70
    context.addServletMappingDecoded( "/rest/*", "CXFServlet" );

    // Enable the JNDI and add the Databases
    apiServer.enableNaming();
    
    // AIS DB
    if ( AISGateway.configuration.getDbDriver() != null ) {
        logger.info( "Configuring AIS Database connection to " + AISGateway.configuration.getDbConnection() );
        ContextResource aisDbResource = new ContextResource();
        aisDbResource.setName( "jdbc/db/ais" );
        aisDbResource.setAuth( "Container" );
        aisDbResource.setType( "javax.sql.DataSource" );
        aisDbResource.setScope( "Sharable" );
        aisDbResource.setProperty( "driverClassName", AISGateway.configuration.getDbDriver() );
        aisDbResource.setProperty( "username", AISGateway.configuration.getDbUser() );
        aisDbResource.setProperty( "password", AISGateway.configuration.getDbPassword() );
        aisDbResource.setProperty( "url", AISGateway.configuration.getDbConnection() );
        Map<String, String> dbExtraProperties = AISGateway.configuration.getDbProperties();
        for( String propertyName : dbExtraProperties.keySet() )
            aisDbResource.setProperty( propertyName, dbExtraProperties.get( propertyName ) );
        context.getNamingResources().addResource(aisDbResource);
    }
    
    // API Shutdown port
    if ( AISGateway.configuration.getApiShutdownPort() != -1 ) {
        apiServer.getServer().setPort( AISGateway.configuration.getApiShutdownPort() );
        logger.info( "API Shutdown Control Port set to " + apiServer.getServer().getPort() );
        if ( AISGateway.configuration.getApiShutdownCommand() != null )
            apiServer.getServer().setShutdown( AISGateway.configuration.getApiShutdownCommand() );
    }

    apiServer.init();
```

Here's the code used by the database manager class. This object is instantiated by Spring, which is configured into Tomcat as a ContextClass parameter:

```
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db/ais");
    if ( dataSource == null )
        throw new GeneralDbException( "Database is not configured" );
    _instance = this;
    logger.info( "AIS DB Manager initialised" );
```

It is at the point the database manager attempts to load the envContext that the following error occurs:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
> at org.xhe.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:na]
> at org.xhe.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:na]
> at org.xhe.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:161) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:na]
> at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409) ~[na:na]
> at com.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.AisDbManager.(AisDbManager.java:38) ~[x-ais-0.3.9.jar:na]
> at com.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.AisDbManager.getInstance(AisDbManager.java:32) ~[x-ais-0.3.9.jar:na]
> at com.x.x.x.x.x.x.SpringWebConfig.AisDbManager(SpringWebConfig.java:91) ~[x-ais-0.3.9.jar:na]
> at com.x.x.x.x.x.x.SpringWebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$204b25de.CGLIB$AisDbManager$10() ~[x-ais-0.3.9.jar:na]
> at com.x.x.x.x.x.x.SpringWebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$204b25de$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5d9fad5.invoke() ~[x-ais-0.3.9.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> at com.x.x.x.x.x.x.SpringWebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$204b25de.AisDbManager() ~[x-ais-0.3.9.jar:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> ... 102 common frames omitted

It had occurred to me there may be a race condition where the Spring Framework it trying to initialize the beans before the JNDI Context is fully populated by Tomcat, so I tried the **@Lazy** annotation in my SpringWebConfig.java code. This didn't work either.

I'm hoping there's some Tomcat setting to make this work.

Any assistance really appreciated.

ADDENDUM:
I added a ContainerListener instance to monitor the state of the container:

```
    public class ApiContainerListener implements ContainerListener {
    public void containerEvent(ContainerEvent event) {
        logger.info( "API Container Event Occurred: " + event.getType() );
        if ( event.getType().equals( "afterContextInitialized" ) ) {
            // Start any other required functions that need the apiServer/spring framework
        }
    }
}
```

The logging shows:

> 2022-07-14 15:26:44,791 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - API Container Event Occurred: addApplicationListener
> 2022-07-14 15:26:44,823 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - API Container Event Occurred: addChild
> 2022-07-14 15:26:44,824 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - API Container Event Occurred: addServletMapping
> 2022-07-14 15:26:44,826 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - Configuring AIS Database connection to jdbc:sqlserver://demosrv:1433;databaseName=scdf-ais
> 2022-07-14 15:26:44,828 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - API Shutdown Control Port set to 8098
> 2022-07-14 15:26:47,354 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - API Container Event Occurred: addValve
> 2022-07-14 15:26:47,751 [main] INFO x.x.x.x.x.x.ais.AISGateway - API Container Event Occurred: beforeContextInitialized
> 2022-07-14 15:26:47,751 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started

It was immediately (47ms) after this that the above errors were logged.

ADDENDUM 2:
By the way, the code works perfectly if run within Eclipse! This means I cannot debug it easily to get to the root cause.

Comment: Regarding your race condition suspicion - did you try adding logs to your Tomcat JNDI initialization and before `initContext.lookup()` in your `AisDbManager` to see what runs first? Also, what's the motivation in using JNDI in an embedded Tomcat instead of, say, a properties file loaded via `@PropertySource`?

Comment: Yes, I added logs and it seemed the Resources were being set up before the attempts by Spring to instantiate its beans. The motivation to use JNDI is historic - it was how it was done at the time I first built embedded Tomcat applications - and it's nice and neat. I try to avoid using properties files as much as possible. People tend to fiddle with them.

Comment: Also, note this works perfectly under Tomcat 7.0.70. The **only** change here is the Tomcat version. Tomcat must have some internal change in the way it handles JNDI JDBC Resources, and this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.